# HTML data to PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<a data-toggle="modal"> 
   data-id="<?php print $row['account_id']; ?>" 
   title="Leltár megtekintése&#013;<?php print $row['account_id']; ?>-s azonosító" 
   class="open-accountID" 
   href="#inventory">
      <i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></I>
</a>
```

How can I get data-id and load to PHP variable?

```
$player_name = data-id(....)
```

But I have 2 php files. The variables are not together. Just I need a character id, from other PHP files when I click a button.

Comment: You already set $row['account_id'] for data-id and you ask for how to get it ? you can pass directly your $row['account_id'] to $player_name without using any other code

Answer (score 1):

You will need to select data-id with Javascript and send data to your backend. With fetch or some other ajax method.

```
<script>
const element = document.querySelector('.open-accountID');
//console.log(element.dataset.id);
</script>
```

With this code you will select data-id attribute.
I commented console.log but with it you can check if select was succesfull.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send it to php you will have to do that through javascript: 
(There's no way fetching the value directly to php)

```
1. fetch data-id from the html-element and save it to a variable in javascript
2. send the value of the variable to php 
via ajax or by redirecting to the php with value of the javascript-variable
```

But you already have the value  so you could do:

```
$player_name = $row['account_id'];
```